# We have to show that if z,w $\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|$z$|<$ 1 and $|$w$|<$ 1 and $\bar{z}$w $\neq$ $\bar{w}$z then we have the following:

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$$\left| (1+|z|^2)w - (1+|w|^2)z \right| > \left| \overline zw - \overline wz  \right|$$

This is the third day in a row that I am working on this problem. I have tried various manipulations like dividing by the product $|$ (1+$|$z$|^{2}$). (1+$|$w$|^{2}$), trying to prove this in polar form and so on.

So far have not gotten anywhere. I am trying to self-learn complex analysis by doing problems but this problem has me stumped.

Comment: Write $$|z|^2=z\cdot\bar z$$ etc.

Comment: You don't need to put every symbol in LaTeX individually. For example |1+z^2|>|1-w^2| with one dollar sign at the start and one at the end will give you $|1+z^2|>|1-w^2|$. Hope this helps :-)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I tried that too.. I am typing what I did in comments.

Comment: The RHS becomes $| w + wz \bar{z} - z - zw\bar{w} |$ .. I had already tried this but haven't seen it I guess clearly.

Comment: @HumbleStudent Was this the original problem, or something you simplified off another problem? The conditions are a bit odd, for example the inequality holds if $\,|z|=|w|\,$ regardless if they are inside the unit circle or not. Also, is the question tagged `complex-analysis` for any particular reason.

Comment: I didn't modify the question. I mentioned in the question, i am self-learning complex analysis from online resources. That is where question comes from..

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying  both $z$ and $w$ with the same factor $e^{i\beta}$ leaves both sides of the stated inequality unchanged. We therefore may assume
$$z=re^{-i\alpha}, \quad w=se^{i\alpha},\qquad 0<r<1,\quad 0<s<1,\quad 0<\alpha<{\pi\over2}\ .\tag{1}$$
The claim then reads
$$\bigl|(1+r^2)s e^{i\alpha}-(1+s^2)re^{-i\alpha}\bigr|>rs\bigl|e^{2i\alpha}-e^{-2i\alpha}\bigr|=2rs\sin(2\alpha)\ ,$$
or
$$\left|{1+r^2\over2r}e^{i\alpha}-{1+s^2\over2s}e^{-i\alpha}\right|>\sin(2\alpha)\ .$$
Put
$${1+r^2\over2r}=:\rho>1,\qquad {1+s^2\over2s}=:\sigma>1\ .$$
We then have to prove that
$$\bigl|\rho e^{i\alpha}-\sigma e^{-i\alpha}\bigr|>\sin(2\alpha)\ .$$
The two points $\rho e^{i\alpha}$ and $\sigma e^{-i\alpha}$ are lying on the two rays in direction $e^{\pm i\alpha}$, and outside of the unit circle. Their distance therefore is $\ >2\sin\alpha>\sin(2\alpha)$.

Comment: I don't think this one works as the question never says that the complex numbers lie on the same ray.. in fact it will contradict the fact that $\bar{z}$w $\neq$ $\bar{w}$z

Comment: Of course $z$ and $w$ don't lie on the same ray; but we can collectively rotate (and if necessary interchange) them such that they lie on two rays in symmetric directions $e^{\pm i\alpha}$, as assumed in $(1)$.